# Which create-react-app files should I add in my github repo?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a react practice project that I want to add in my github repo. I used create-react-app and there are many folders. I tried adding the whole project folder but it says the size is too big. Which folders should I put there? Also I want to be able to deploy it with netlify.

Comment: Git ignore file should be placed in your project repository, which only include required files only.   [purpose of gitignore](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-purpose-of-a-gitignore-file) and you need to include  [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/.gitignore) file

Comment: create-react-app should already have included a `.gitignore` file that will automatically exclude unnecessary files from being added to git repo.